# time format from MySQL database column is unrecognisable

Tags: mysql, database, date, time, format

I have a Mysql database table and it has a column "Created time" which has values like 1538899092000 , 1543476095000 and so on.
What is this ? and how to convert this into our regular format ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a Unix timestamp multiplied by 1,000 (i.e. in milliseconds rather than seconds).  These kinds of timestamps are used in JavaScript.

Use `FROM_UNIXTIME(created_time/1000)` to convert it to a `DATETIME`.

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1543476095000/1000);
+-----------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1543476095000/1000) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2018-11-29 01:21:35               |
+-----------------------------------+
```

And use `1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime value)` to convert a `DATETIME` to this format.

Comment: wow. Great help man. Appreciate it. one more thing , i need to find record of last three months and table has only this  values for created time. so , how to find last 3 months of data from this time and date format ?

Comment: `WHERE created_time > 1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`

Comment: You are a Legend ! a superhero ! always remember that. Thanks